# pass multiple arguments __doPostBack

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Is it possible to pass multiple arguments in the __doPostBack call?
I Know how I use one arrgument
 `__doPostBack('Service', $("input[name=celservice]:checked").val());`

and in code behind vb.net

```
If eventTarget = "Service" Then
'Something
EndIf
```

but how when I use two arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have created our own library to pass data from web page to ASP.NET. Without getting too much into details, the javascript code wraps info into an XML stream (you can use JSON just as well) that is then parsed on the server.


At its core, our javascript object looks something like this:

```
function MyArgs() {
    var args = '';

    this.add = function (id, value) {
        args += ('<param id="' + encodeURI(id) + '" value="' + encodeURI(value) + '" />');
    };

    this.output = function () {
        return '<request>' + args + '</request>';
    };
}
```

And we use it like this:

```
var args = new MyArgs();
args.add("param1", "value A");
args.add("param2", "Value B");

__doPostBack("YOUR_SERVICE", args.output());
```

We like it because we are quite comfortable with XML data, but you may as well use JSON or URL encoding. The logic is the same: you create a stream that you can parse on the server. 


This technique is also useful the other way around, server to client, especially as a response to AJAX requests.


I hope this may be of help to you :)

Comment: You are very welcome. If you think this answer helped solve your problem, I would appreciate it if you flagged it as the correct answer :)

Comment: I'm sorry I can't..because I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: No problem. I am happy I could help you out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your multiple results in an object, like so:

```
var result = {
    celservice: $("input[name=celservice]:checked").val(),
    somethingElse: true
}
```

then

```
__doPostBack('Service', result);
```